# Compare Nested Object Field to Array List in Javasacript/Lodash

Tags: javascript, arrays, lodash

I have the following 2 pieces of data:

users:

```
[ 
   {id:1, food:{id:2, name:"coffee"} },
   {id:2, food:{id:3, name:"tea" } },
   {id:3, food:{id:5, name:"salad"} }
]
```

foodList:

```
[2,3]
```

I'm currently using react and I need to filter out the users to only show those with food id's from the FoodList array.

I tried something like this in Lodash:

```
 var filtered = _.some(users.food.id, foodList);
```

This is incorrect since users.food.id is not valid. Is there a way to compare a nested object array to a list in javascript?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a nice and short lodash solution to this problem, that you can use if you're already using lodash.

Index the values using [`_.keyBy()`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.2#keyBy), and extract only those that are in the `footList` using [`_.at()`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.2#at):

```js
var data = [{ id: 1, food: { id: 2, name: "coffee" } }, { id: 2, food: { id: 3, name: "tea" } }, { id: 3, food: { id: 5, name: "salad" } }]

var foodList = [2,3];

var result = _(data) // start the chain
  .keyBy('id') // index the items by key
  .at(foodList) // get the items
  .value(); // return the result array

console.log(result);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.2/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `Array.prototype.filter`

```
const result = users.filter(e => foodList.includes(e.food.id));
```

[MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Objets_globaux/Array/filter)

Answer (score 1):

This is simple task that you can do without any library. You can just use `filter()` and `indexOf()`

```js
var data = [ 
   {id:1, food:{id:2, name:"coffee"} },
   {id:2, food:{id:3, name:"tea"} },
   {id:3, food:{id:5, name:"salad"} }
]

var arr = [2,3];
var result = data.filter(e => arr.indexOf(e.food.id) != -1)
console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use [`_.filter`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.2#filter) and [`_.includes`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.2#includes) from lodash.

```js
var users = [{ id: 1, food: { id: 2, name: "coffee" } }, { id: 2, food: { id: 3, name: "tea" } }, { id: 3, food: { id: 5, name: "salad" } }],
    foodList = [2, 3],
    result = _.filter(users, u => _.includes(foodList, u.food.id));

console.log(result);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.15.0/lodash.min.js"></script>
```